# Oracle - EXP-00001: data field truncation - column length=50, buffer size=50 actual size=51

Tags: oracle

What does this error actually mean?

EXP-00001: data field truncation - column length=50, buffer size=50 actual size=51

I get it while exporting dump for my oracle database.

Does it mean that my data is too big already and cannot be exported anymore?

Currently running oracle 11g xe and database size is already at 10gb

Thank you for your insights.

Comment: why are you using exp and not expdp? try with that it may go thru

Comment: PLease update your question to include the _complete and exact_ command that you issued and the complete output.  Paste it directly into your message - no links.

Comment: Also include the character set of the database, the nls settings of the exporting session and the exact definition of the column that is hit by this. More specifically: the length of that column, is that specified in bytes or characters?

Comment: From the error I can say, You are exporting the data into a column whose length is only 50 but data's actual length in at least 1 row is more than 50. Hence the error.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai - unless I'm missing something, this is an _export_ operation.  The data is read from a table in the db, and written to a binary dmp file.  Only on the follow-on _import_ would it attempt to insert into a table, where that would matter.